# Is it okay to navigate out from a wizard flow to direct user to a certain page to accomplish their task?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design

[image]
I’m currently designing a flow where users are to link an bank. The scenario is the user wants to add another account from a bank, but while on the wizard, he sees that the bank has already been link.

- The first step of the wizard is to search and select a bank from the list which would open a modal.
- Let’s say the user searched for “ABC” and it came back with multiple results
- He then saw that the bank he wanted to add has already been linked to the app.
- Below the bank name, it says “Bank already linked. Go to manage account to add another account.”  - but the problem is it will link out and leave the wizard. It will ask the user to confirm to disregard any changes and be directed to the link he clicked, but is this flow really okay?

The concern with having a link is it may be seen as disrupting the directed flow. I’m thinking that having a link is offering a shortcut to the user, but some thinks it’s better to not have it because the question is more of “how can they go back?”. My assumption is, if they need to add an account to an already linked bank, then they wouldn’t need to go back.

What are your thoughts on this?

P.S
We don’t have user testing at the moment so this is a bit challenging. Also due to tech constraints we are stuck with this flow - we couldn’t allow users select a linked bank on this wizard and thus we can only suggest for them to go to their manage account settings to add another account under that bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to give the user a shortcut to complete the desired task is a good idea. But it should be clear to the user what is happening.

As I understand, the step to add a bank is the first step in the wizard. If so, it is not necessary to show a discard message to the user because no changes where made. If the selection of the bank is not the first step it get's more difficult.

What I would do in addition is to communicate the fact, that only new banks (and not bank accounts) can be added with the wizard before starting the wizard. This can be done either with an explanatory text (which will be overread by many users) or by asking in the first step of the wizard. And in addition make clear to the user that she leaves the wizard, when clicking on the 'add account' option. This can be achieved by clearly describe the action. Something like 'leave wizard go to account' or 'discard changes and go to account settings'

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I also agree with not having to show a discard message since no changes were made as this is the first step. One idea is to also make it clear that the CTA from the overview page is “Link Bank” because currently our CTA has the word “account” in it which would make it confusing. These are good points and will keep these in mind on my iteration.